# How to parse array from JsonArray?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have JSON array like

```
"Headlines": [
        {
            "Title": "SPYRUS Announces Support for Windows To Go 10 Preview",
            "Date": "2/18/2015",
            "UTCOffset": 0,
            "Source": "Marketwire - News Releases",
            "Url": "http://www.redinews.com/news/?story=201502151176008.html",
            "Images": [],
                "Tags": [
                    {
                        "TagType": "Symbols",
                        "TagValues": [
                            "MSFT"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "TagType": "Companies",
                        "TagValues": [
                            "Microsoft Corporation"
                        ]
                    },
```

I am accessing "Headlines" with this code using org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser

```
 JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
 JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(obj);
 JSONArray lang = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Headlines");

 System.out.println(lang);
```

but I need access "Tags" sub array and get TagType and TagValues

How to access it?
will be good also know how to parse sub array with org.codehaus.jackson.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

see this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/).

it explains how to iterate over an json array

the code should be something like this

```
JSONArray headlines = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Headlines");
    Iterator<String> iterator = headlines.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
 JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(obj);
 JSONArray lang = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Headlines");

JSONArray tag = lang.getJSONArray("tag");  

for (int i = 0; i < tag .length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONArray temp= jsonobject .getJSONArray("TagValues"); 

        String tagValue = temp.getString(0);
        String tagType = jsonobject.getString("TagType");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code which really work, used simple json and org.codehaus.jackson togheter.

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(obj);
                            JSONArray lang = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Headlines");
                            for (int i = 0; i < lang.size(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonobject = (JSONObject) lang.get(i);
                                Object subArray = jsonobject.get("Tags");
                                ObjectMapper mapperNew = new ObjectMapper();
                                JsonFactory factoryNew = mapperNew.getJsonFactory();
                                JsonParser jpNew;
                                System.out.println("sub Array " + subArray.toString());
                                jpNew = factoryNew.createJsonParser(subArray.toString());
                                JsonNode inputNew = mapperNew.readTree(jpNew);
                                 for (final JsonNode elementNew : inputNew) {
                                      Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> nodeIterator3 = elementNew.getFields();
                                       while (nodeIterator3.hasNext()) {
                                              Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry3 = (Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>) nodeIterator3.next();
                                               if (entry3.getKey() != null && entry3.getKey().equals("TagType")) {
                                                      System.out.println("TagType "  + entry3.getValue());
                                                 }
                                                 if (entry3.getKey() != null && entry3.getKey().equals("TagValues")) {
                                                      System.out.println("TagValues " + entry3.getValue());
                                                 }
                                       }
                                 }
```